# Unauthorized AJAX requests returning statuscode 200 instead of 401

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

In MVC 5, I override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest()` and check if the request is from AJAX.

I have also registrated a Global `ajaxComplete`, for handeling 401 AJAX requests, but the status code is still 200 after being in `HandleUnauthorizedRequest()`.

**Question:** Do I have to manually change the statuscode in `filterContext` in the function `HandleUnauthorizedRequest()`?

**Unauthorized AJAX request detected**

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        // <-- in here
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new
            {
                returnUrl = "foo"
            },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
    else
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**Global ajaxComplete registration**

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, settings) {
    console.log('xhr.status: "' + xhr.status +'"'); // 200 - i want 401
    if(xhr.status === 401) {
        window.location.replace(urlHelper.getUrlNotAuthorized());
    }
});
```

***"Working but hacked solution until I find a solution with ajaxComplete.***

It check if the Users request was authorized. Downside is that I have to check `isAuthorized()` everyway i make a request. That's why I would like to use a global ajaxComplete, so I never miss one.":

**Check if the Users AJAX request was authorized**

```
isAuthorized = function (result) {
    try {
        var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(result) || $.parseJSON(result);
        // Here, obj can still be a parsed JsonResult, from when getting GetDatatableRows(), so we also need to check on returnUrl which is distinct
        // obj will only contain returnUrl if the JSON was returned from Shield validation
        if (obj && obj.returnUrl) {
            window.location.replace(urlHelper.getUrlNotAuthorized() + '?returnUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(obj.returnUrl));
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }
    return true;
};
```

**AJAX request where result is either a Partial View or JSON**

```
partialViewService.changePartialViewService(url, data)
.done(function (result) {
    if (isAuthorized(result)) {
        // use result
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - I haven't checked this, but try adding the line indicated. Specifying code 401 does not filter through to the result you want. (I suspect this is due to Identity intercepting code 401 specifically):

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        // Add this (code 401 does not work)
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 412;
        // <-- in here
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new
            {
                returnUrl = "foo"
            },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
    else
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually that's what I just tryed (with and without two extra lines too)                 filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Close();
But with no luck, the statuscode remains "200" im so confused. I will check one more time just for you though.

Comment: I still got "200":
xhr.status: "200" and xhr.statusCode().status: "200"

Comment: Hmm. This code should be encapsulated in something like: public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    { } - and then you have to make sure that your actions are "decorated" with [CustomAuthorize] - on a base controller, the controller or on individual actions - if you don't add this, the custom code won't kick in. Have you checked that your actions are decorated with your equivalent [] ?

Comment: Yes I have "[ShieldAuthorize, ShieldWebUserCmpBu, ShieldWebUserRight]" on all my controllers. "ShieldAuthorize" is my "CustomAuthorizeAttribute".
I override AuthorizeCore too: "    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            return false; // The user is not authorized => no need to go any further
        }
        return true;
    }
"

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Meanwhile I have added a working but hacked version, that doesn't uses ajaxComplete yet. Here I can ask on "returnUrl" instead of statuscode, but problem is that I have to remember to call the validation method every places, and that's bounded to fail at some time.

Comment: @radbyx - very odd - from what I can see, specifying any code other than 401 works. I very much suspect that this is Identity intercepting the 401 code somewhere in the pipeline, but I can't say for sure without digging further. Try code 412 (precondition failed) and see if that works.

Comment: "xhr.status: "412"" I think I have what I need to build a complete not-hacked solution now, that takes care of the requests **one place**.
This is brilliant. You are a genius - thanks alot.